# python dataframe :dropping rows that the value of all column is a certain value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

There is a dataframe, like the following :

```
   id       a            b           c            d              e
    a     23_2_1     34_55_0    34_55_0      -1_-1_-1        34_55_0
    b     3_55_0    34_55_0   34_55_0       34_55_0          34_55_0
    c     -1_-1_-1    34_55_0   34_55_0       34_55_0        -1_-1_-1
    d     34_55_0    -1_-1_-1   34_55_0       34_55_0        34_55_0
    e     34_55_0    34_55_0   34_55_0       34_55_0         34_55_0
    f     34_55_0    34_55_0   34_55_0       34_55_0         34_55_0
```

I want to delete the  rows that if there is value of columns is '-1_-1_-1' in the dataframe, and also extract the id that include the '-1_-1_-1'.

My trying:

```
lst_col = list(df.columns)[:-1]
df2 = df_bl[~df_bl[lst_col].isin(['-1_-1_-1'])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the values you care about:

```
match_cells = df == '-1_-1_-1'
```

That gives you a DataFrame with True wherever the indicated value is, and False elsewhere.

Now select the rows that have a match:

```
match_rows = match_cells.any(axis=1)
```

Then take the rows without matches:

```
df2 = df[~match_rows]
```

And get the row labels with matches:

```
match_ids = df.index[match_rows]
```